# Paging not working with Pug and Datatables

Tags: node.js, datatables, pug

Unable to get paging ( have 11 entries , but always show single page )
Paging not working with Pug and Datatables and sorting as well not working , however table data is displaying fine with page entries... but always remains with single page

*Script*

```
      script(type='text/javascript', src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js')
      script(type='text/javascript', src='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js')
      script.
       $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#cbs-table').DataTable({
          searching: false,
          paging: true,
          "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
          "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
          ordering: true});
       });
```

**table**

```
      table#cbs-table(div='')
       thead
        each row in jobsHeader
         tr
          th#cbs-tab-header(div='') Edit
          th#cbs-tab-header(div='') !{row.jobname}
          th#cbs-tab-header(div='') !{row.job_type}
          th#cbs-tab-header(div='') !{row.autosys_instance}
          th#cbs-tab-header(div='') !{row.milestones}
          th#cbs-tab-header(div='') !{row.parent_milestones}
          th#cbs-tab-header(div='') !{row.group_names}
          th#cbs-tab-header(div='') !{row.region}
          th#cbs-tab-header(div='') !{row.sla}
          th#cbs-tab-header(div='') !{row.sla_amber}
          th#cbs-tab-header(div='') !{row.down_feedname}
          th#cbs-tab-header(div='') !{row.up_feedname}
          th#cbs-tab-header(div='') !{row.notes}
          th#cbs-tab-header(div='') Change History
        each row in slaJobs
         tbody
          tr
           td#cbs-med
            form#cbs_edit(action='/cbs_job_edit' method='POST')
             input(type='image', src='./images/edit.png' height='20', width='20' alt='.')
             input#cbs_edit_all(type='hidden', name='edit_all', value=row.all)
           td#cbs-med !{row.jobname}
           td#cbs-med !{row.job_type}
           td#cbs-med !{row.autosys_instance}
           td#cbs-med !{row.milestones}
           td#cbs-med !{row.parent_milestones}
           td#cbs-med !{row.group_names}
           td#cbs-med !{row.region}
           td#cbs-med !{row.sla}
           td#cbs-med !{row.sla_amber}
           td#cbs-med !{row.down_feedname}
           td#cbs-med !{row.up_feedname}
           td#cbs-big !{row.notes}
           td#cbs-med
            form#test(action='/test'  method='POST')
             input(type='image', src='./images/history.png' height='25', width='25' alt='.')
             input#cbs_history_job(type='hidden', name='job_history', value=row.jobname)
      br
```

Comment: Please help to check if you have any suggestions pls @9162901

Comment: Please help to check if you have any suggestions pls @jora

Answer (score 0):

Resolved : tbody was placed wrongly